# How to remove LimitRange from default namespace in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

For one of requirements , i created a new pod on my default name space using below yaml file

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: LimitRange
 metadata:
 name: mem-min-max-demo-lr1
 spec:
 limits:
 - max:
  memory: 5Gi
 min:
  memory: 900Mi
 type: Container
```

Now i need to remove these LimitRange from  default namespace in kubernetes?

Comment: Does a `kubectl delete` not work?

Comment: no ,more over when i ran `kubectl get pods --namespace=default` i cant even see the pod named `mem-min-max-demo-lr1`  ,but `kubectl create -f` said pod created

Comment: I think maybe you are confusing pods and limitranges?

Answer (score 6):

You created a LimitRange named `mem-min-max-demo-lr1` in the default namespace. To verify run `kubectl get LimitRange -n default` , then delete `kubectl delete LimitRange mem-min-max-demo-lr1` . To further understand this scenario please check this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-constraint-namespace/

Answer (score 0):

To list all limitrange:

```
kubectl describe limitrange
```

To delete one of the limitrange:

```
kubectl delete limitrange *limitrange_name*
```